# I got a message with this erro Function ‘areacircle’ requires an argument list ,Why?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

this is the program. and I got an error why?

```
  ''''code'''''
```

I don't know why the whole doesn't appear, I tried to determine the area and volume for a random number.
----------------why-------------
'''Fortran

```
'program exercise2'
!
      integer :: N,i
      type :: Values
      double precision :: radius,area,volume
      end type
!
!
      type(Values),allocatable, dimension(:) :: s
      integer :: bi
!
!Read the data to create the random number
      write(6,*) 'write your number '
      read(5,*) N
      allocate(s(N))
      bi = 3.14
!create the random number
      call random_seed()
      do i=1,N
        call random_number(s(i)%radius)
        s(i)%area=areacircle(s(i)%radius)
        s(i)%volume=volumesphere(s(i)%radius)
      end do
!
      open(15,file='radius.out',status='new')
      write(15,*) s(i)%radius
      open(16,file='output2.out',status='new')
      r = real(s(i)%radius)
!Two function
      contains
      
      double precision function areacircle (s)
      implicit none
      double precision :: s
      do i=1 , N
         areacircle=bi*r**2
      end do
      return
      end function areacircle
!
!
      double precision function volumesphere (s)
      implicit none
      double precision :: s
      do i=1,N
         volumesphere=4/3*bi*r**3
      end do
      return
      write(16,*)  r    ,     areacircle   ,     volumesphere
      end function volumesphere
'end program exercise2'
```

'''''''
so anyone know why?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but it might be because the function ‘areacircle’ requires an argument list . Go through the code, look at every use of areacircle, and see if you can sort out which one it might be. Also use Implicit None. Always.

Comment: Also the formatting of you question needs sorting - especially where you report the error message. As I don't have the text of the message I can't fix it.

Comment: Presumably the error comes from the statement `write(16,*)  r    ,     areacircle   ,     volumesphere` (as Ian Bush states, we'd all benefit from seeing the exact error message). What are you trying to do with that statement, as you certainly can't print the function `areacircle`.

Comment: So what should I write in argument and in the print
The error is an areacircle need an argument this is the message I got

Comment: Your function for computing the volume is incorrect.  The factor `4/3` is integer division, which results in a value of one.  In addition, you declare `bi` to be integer, but try to assign `3.14` to it with the statement `bi = 3.14`.  This means `bi` has the value of `3` after assignment.  So, your volume computation becomes simply `volumesphere=r**3`.

Comment: Now I solved the first problem but I need the function to know that the radius is the random value to can use it for volume and area

Comment: @Abd-ElazeemMohamed As suggested in the answer by evets below, I recommend to give the `result` clause for each function, such that the name of the result variable is specified explicitly (it can be any variable name you like). In your original code, in this line "write(16, * ) r, areacircle, volumesphere", `volumesphere` means the result variable, while `areacirle` is interpreted as a function call (by the compiler), which may lead to your confusion.. (And you can pass `s` as "write(16, * ) r, areacircle( s ), volumesphere" in the original code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely does what you want.  As the computation of area and volume involve a single input that does not change, I've changed your functions to be `elemental`.  This allows an array argument where the function is executed for each element of the array.  I also changed `double precision` to use Fortran kind type parameter mechanism, because typing is `real(dp)` is much shorter.
Finally, never write a Fortran program without the `implicit none` statement.

```
program exercise2

  implicit none ! Never write a program without this statement

  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)  !  kind type parameter
  integer n, i
  type values
     real(dp) radius, area, volume
  end type

  type(values), allocatable :: s(:)
  real(dp) bi  ! integer :: bi?

  ! Read the data to create the random number
  write(6,*) 'write your number '
  read(5,*) n

  ! Validate n is validate.
  if (n < 1) stop 'Invalid number'

  allocate(s(n))

  bi = 4 * atan(1.d0)  !   bi = 3.14?  correctly determine pi

  call random_seed()                  ! Use default seeding
  call random_number(s%radius)        ! Fill radii with random numbers
  s%area   = areacircle(s%radius)     ! Compute area  
  s%volume = volumesphere(s%radius)   ! Compute volume

  write(*,'(A)') '   Radii    Area    Volume'
  do i = 1, n
     write(*, '(3F9.5)') s(i)
  end do

  contains
  
     elemental function areacircle(s) result(area)
        real(dp) area
        real(dp), intent(in) :: s
        area = bi * s**2
     end function areacircle

     elemental function volumesphere(s) result(volume)
        real(dp) volume
        real(dp), intent(in) :: s
        volume = (4 * bi / 3) * s**3
     end function volumesphere
end program exercise2
```